# How to make a spaghetti plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, interaction

I have the following:
heads(dataframe):

```
ID Result Days 

1   70     0         
1   80     23
2   90     15
2   89     30
2   99     40
3   23     24
```

ect...
what I am trying to do is: Create a spaghetti plot with the above datast. What I use is this:

`interaction.plot(dataframe$Days,dataframe$ID,dataframe$Result,xlab="Time",ylab="Results",legend=F)` but none of the patient lines are continuous even when they were supposed to be a long line.

Also I want to convert the above dataframe to something like this: 
ID Result Days

```
1   70     0         
1   80     23
2   90     0
2   89     15
2   99     25
3   23     0
```

ect... ( I am trying to take the first (or minimum) of each id and have their dating starting from zero and up). Also in the spaghetti plot i want all patients to have the same color IF a condition in met, and another color if the condition is not met.

Thank you for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this, using ggplot2 and data.table

```
# libs
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

# your data
df <- data.table(ID=c(1,1,2,2,2,3),
                 Result=c(70,80,90,89,99,23),
                 Days=c(0,23,15,30,40,24))

# adjust each ID to start at day 0, sort
df <- merge(df, df[, list(min_day=min(Days)), by=ID], by='ID')
df[, adj_day:=Days-min_day]
df <- df[order(ID, Days)]

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x=adj_day, y=Result, color=factor(ID))) +
  geom_line() + geom_point() +
  theme_bw()
```

Contents of updated data.frame (actually a data.table):

```
 ID Result Days min_day adj_day
  1     70    0       0       0
  1     80   23       0      23
  2     90   15      15       0
  2     89   30      15      15
  2     99   40      15      25
  3     23   24      24       0
```

[image: Plot output]
You can handle the color coding easily using scale_color_manual()

Comment: for the data.table part: I have 9.200 lines... how should I adjust that part? Is this the option: dataframe$id ect?

Comment: I just realized I misunderstood what you asked about adjusting days such that the minimum is zero. See updated code. I'm not sure what you are asking about data.table, but "df$ID" is a valid way to access the ID column of data.table "df", yes

Comment: Yes, that's what I was going to tell you now. Ty

Comment: Could the derivation be simplified to `df$adj_day <- ave(df$Days, df$ID, FUN=function(i)  i-i[1])` (if using dataframes)

Comment: It works!! Thanks man!!! You are awesome...One last thing, I want all the IDS to have the same color unless there is a statement fulfilled, when the color should be RED let's say (only two colors in the graph: black and red.
I do that with an IF command?

Comment: Let's say the condition was "id >= 2", then you could use: id_colors <- ifelse(c(1,2,3) >= 2, 'red', 'black') and then add +scale_color_manual(values=id_colors) to the end of the collection of ggplot commands (after theme_bw())

Comment: @user20650: sure, i see that works too (even with data.table)