# Creating separate line graphs in R using Excel sheet containing ID, date of collection, and other variables using readxl

Tags: r, excel, readxl

My Excel sheet looks like:

```
ID .   Date_of_Collection . RBCblood . WBCblood . .......   
23456 .  7/30/19 .           2 .        3 . ....    
23456 .  8/7/19 .            4 .        6 . ....    
43562 .  2/13/16 .           5 .        7 . .... 
and so on
```

I am trying to make graphs for each patient's RBCblood count over time (date_of_collection) and make sure there are separate lines for each patient by ID.  I am new to R and it's been difficult merging the data by ID.

Comment: Maybe provide the spreadsheet in Google Sheets or something. It's difficult to understand what you posted here.

Comment: These are really two separate issues.  The first is reading from Excel (I see your [readxl] tag) into a data.frame.  The second is creating a [spaghetti plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25291883/how-to-make-a-spaghetti-plot-in-r).  There shouldn't be any "merging" necessary (as it's usually defined).